# Axios in VueJS is mixing the urls. localhost + URL giving error. Should be just the URL

Tags: vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, vue-cli

I'have created a project with Vue-cli and the axios get request is not working as spected.

```
axios.get("​https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/​pokemon")
        .then(response => {
          this.pokemons = response.data;
          console.log(this.pokemons);
        })
```

The request URL throws `http://localhost:8080/%E2%80%8Bhttps://pokeapi.co/api/v2/%E2%80%8Bpokemon`
.

It should juts be `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/%E2%80%8Bpokemon` but that localhost is messing things up.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 zero width spaces in your string one at the beginning and one before `pokemon`.
This may have been caused by pasting code from a word processor.
The one at the beginning is making your URL be interpreted as a relative URL.
Remove the spaces and your url should be requested as expected.